# Lock range of Cells in row based on adjacent cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I am using vba code to review and Approve certain row of data using two set of sheets:
1st is "View_Form" where we review the entered data in specific form view.
2nd is "Tracker" where all the data is stored from external download.

In "View_Form" sheet we select File ID and all the data relevant to it get displayed and if all looks good we Click macro button "Approved" and the text "Approved" gets in the Column HR adjacent to the selected file ID else it would be blank.

Its working but we are still able to edit the "Approved" row which I want to restrict. That is if the HR cell contains text "Approved" that particular row from A:HR should get locked or should restrict the user from editing.

Should enable user to edit after using password to unprotect sheet say for example password as 123.

Can any one help me out with this...

Current code for approval:

```
Sub Approval()
Dim found As Range 'define variables
Dim SelectedFileID As String

'Approval function
SelectedFileID = Sheets("View_Form").Range("SelFileID").Value 'get the currently selected File ID

Set found = Sheets("Tracker").Range("B:B").Find(What:=SelectedFileID) 'find the file ID in the Sheet Tracker
    If Not found Is Nothing Then 'if found
        Sheets("Tracker").Cells(found.Row, 226).Value = "Approved" 'change the value of the row it was found, but column 226 which is column HR
    Else
        MsgBox "ID not found in Sheet Tracker!", vbInformation 'if not found then show message
    End If
    ActiveWorkbook.Save '---------------Save workbook
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will lock all the rows where Column 226 contains "Approved" (You can still unlock by using the password):

```
Sub Picture1_Click()
Dim found As Range 'define variables
Dim SelectedFileID As String

SelectedFileID = Sheets("View_Form").Range("SelFileID").Value 'get the currently selected File ID
Application.DisplayAlerts = False    
Set found = Sheets("Tracker").Range("B:B").Find(What:=SelectedFileID) 'find the file ID in the Sheet Tracker
    If Not found Is Nothing Then 'if found
        Sheets("Tracker").Unprotect Password:="1234" 'change the password to whatever you wish, this unlocks the sheet
        Sheets("Tracker").Cells(found.Row, 226).Value = "Approved" 'change the value of the row it was found, but column 226 which is column HR
        Sheets("Tracker").Range("A1:HR500").Cells.Locked = False 'keeps range unlocked
        LastRow = Sheets("Tracker").Cells(Sheets("Tracker").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 3 To LastRow
            If Sheets("Tracker").Cells(i, 226).Value = "Approved" Then
                Sheets("Tracker").Rows(i).Cells.Locked = True
            End If
        Next i
        Sheets("Tracker").Protect Password:="1234" 'protect the sheet after updating to Approved on Column HR
    Else
        MsgBox "ID not found in Sheet Tracker!", vbInformation 'if not found then show message
    End If
ActiveWorkbook.Save '---------------Save workbook
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: getting two error message as variable lastrow and "i" not found. however, I amended the code with Dim Lastrow As Long & Dim i As Long and its working by locking entire row. Thanks for your help.

Comment: i observed with the above code Approval code runs only once a it says ID not found in sheet Tracker where as it available. I made few changes as well in the above code with cell count.

Comment: @Sanoj, this works for me as expected, the first comment you made was because you are using Option Explicit and I wasn't, so VBA was telling you to declare the variables, but I don't understand your recent comment, as the ID is selected in the drop down of View_Form, so I guess it has to do with how you populate that listbox...

Comment: pasted the code again and working fine thanks for your help.